# how to get raw message with microsoft graph?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I want to know how to get raw message from microsoft graph, as 
`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}` return json object, and I need rfc822 of mails.

Comment: You will be able to get it by performing EWS request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please refer to [Get MIME content of a message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message) for a description and examples of the two ways one can get a message in raw (MIME) format.

In general, keeping an eye on the [Microsoft Graph blog site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/mime-format-support-for-outlook-mail-and-attachments-translate-item-id-apis-are-now-available-in-microsoft-graph-v1-0/), the [what's new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/whats-new-earlier#september-2019-new-and-generally-available) topic, or the [changelog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog#september-2019)  topic (if it's API or permissions updates) would help you discover additions and updates you were looking for. In particular, the ability to get the MIME format of a message or message type attachment was introduced in April 2019 in the beta version, and promoted to v1.0 in September a few months later.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to now be available. I haven't tested it for myself yet though...

> Today, we’re excited to announce  general availability of the
>   following Microsoft Graph APIs:
>
> Retrieve contents of an email message in MIME format Download file and
>   item attachments in their raw format Translate identifiers of
>   Outlook-related resources between formats You can now use these APIs
>   in Graph v1.0 to implement production apps that require access to the
>   raw contents of an email message or an attachment. You can download
>   file attachments in binary format or item attachments in MIME format.
>   Also, you can translate the format of identifiers of multiple
>   resources by specifying the source and target ID types.
>
> These APIs had been among our top user asks and we’re happy to roll
>   these out on v1.0 endpoint worldwide. You can access these APIs on the
>   v1.0 endpoint by using syntax like the following:
>
> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{message-id}/$value

[source](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/mime-format-support-for-outlook-mail-and-attachments-translate-item-id-apis-are-now-available-in-microsoft-graph-v1-0/)

[original uservoice request](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/12253464-expose-the-entire-email-mime-stream-whole-mail-co)

[using the sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825319/how-to-pass-value-in-request-to-get-mime-content-of-mail-using-graph-sdk-not-ap/57830195#57830195)